# Android Calling objects from fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm not sure the best way to go about what I intend to do.  I have an app that involves three fragments, each navigated to by a single activity that has a navigation drawer.

I have a text to speech class that initialises the text to speech engine.  The problem is, is that it needs to be used by multiple different fragments.  My idea was to create an object of the TTS class in the main Activity and extend functions so that they can be called by the fragments, like so:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mTextToSpeechService = ((NavigationActivity)this.getActivity()).GetTextToSpeechService();
    }
```

The problem I see here is, what if I need to do something such as change the language within one fragment.  That would mean I'd have to expose another function to set the TTS class within the activity, which doesn't seem right.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Is the goal to have different languages in the different fragments or should they always be the same?

Comment: They should always be the same.  So essentially, the TextToSpeechService object should always be the same.  If I change the language in one fragment, the other fragment should also reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

There are three options:

- Inherit from application and store singleton there. You can see how to do that [here](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/androids-application-class/).
- Create started service and use it from activity.(not bounded) See the [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).
- Store language setting in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) and apply them to textspeech engine in activity lifecycle methods (onResume method).

Services are designed for tasks which are not connected to UI. If it's too much work to be done you may find third option to be a candidate for this particular problem.

Comment: Isn't a service a bit of overkill for such a simple task?

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether it's a simple task or not. It's up to author to decide. Even though I've added 3-rd option.